# Php base64 and ruby are not the same result

Tags: php, ruby, base64

I am trying to convert my php code into ruby by using Base64 but they do not give the same results;

PHP code;

```
<?php
$user_basket = base64_encode( json_encode( array(array("My basket", "18.00", 2))));

echo $user_basket;
?>
```

which outputs;

```
W1siTXkgYmFza2V0IiwiMTguMDAiLDJdXQ==
```

Then I try the same thing in ruby;

```
user_basket = Base64.encode64((([["My basket", "18.00", 2]]).to_json).gsub!(/\"/, '\''))
```

I put gsub because `to_json` adds **backslashes**.

this outputs;

```
"W1snTXkgYmFza2V0JywnMTguMDAnLDJdXQ==\n"
```

**EDIT:**

The problem is with the to_json conversation;
In php the output is;

```
json_encode( array(array("My basket", "18.00", 2)))
>> [["My basket","18.00",2]]
```

In ruby;

```
([["My basket", "18.00", 2]]).to_json
>> "[[\"My basket\",\"18.00\",2]]"
```

ruby adds backslash that is why I add gsub to remove backslashes.

Comment: `json_econde()` and `.to_json` produce identical string outputs? I am not familiar with ruby but shouldn't it be `.to_json.gsub!(`? It looks like there are too many parenthesis?

Comment: The difference in outputs is because your ruby uses single quotes and php uses double quotes, these are the decodes: PHP: `[["My basket","18.00",2]]`, 
RUBY: `[['My basket','18.00',2]]`

Comment: Then how Can I replace single quote with the double quote ?

Comment: well i dont get how ruby's `.to_json` returns single quotes as the json specification says: **A value can be a string in double quotes, or a number, or true or false or null, or an object or an array. These structures can be nested.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither Ruby's `to_json` not PHP's `json_encode` add back slashes to the actual string. However, when printing the string in IRB, backslashes are added in this displayed representation to be a valud string. They are not in the actual string data however.

In contrast what @Neat said in his comment, Ruby also doesn't add single-quites in its JSON output. With your original code however, the would be present since you are replacing all literal double-quote characters with a single quote character with your `gsub!`.

The confusion probably stems from you forgetting the actual `json_encode` call in your PHP version. When running the actual code, both versions produce the exact same string:

```
PHP> json_encode( array(array("My basket", "18.00", 2)));
# => "[[\"My basket\",\"18.00\",2]]"

RUBY> [["My basket", "18.00", 2]].to_json
# => "[[\"My basket\",\"18.00\",2]]"
```

When encoding the string as base64, the result is thus also the same:

```
PHP> base64_encode( json_encode( array(array("My basket", "18.00", 2))));
# => "W1siTXkgYmFza2V0IiwiMTguMDAiLDJdXQ=="

RUBY> Base64.strict_encode64 [["My basket", "18.00", 2]].to_json
# => "W1siTXkgYmFza2V0IiwiMTguMDAiLDJdXQ=="
```